# How can I modify the first for loop in this java method into a recursive call?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, combinations

This is a problem for an Algorithms course I'm taking that I can't figure out.

```
// modify the array x to generate the next k-combination from x.
// In general, the first k-combination of n elements is { 1, 2, ..., k } 
// and the last k-combination is { n-k+1, n-k+2, ..., n }.
public static boolean nextCombination (int x[], int k, int n) {
    for (int j = k-1; j >= 0; j--) 
         if (x[j] <= (n - k + j)) {
             x[j]++;  
             for (int i = 1; i < k - j;  i++)
                   x[i+j] = x[j]+i;
             return true; 
         }
    return false;
}
```

It gets called by this method:

```
// print all k-combinations of n elements.
public static void enumerateCombinations (int k, int n) {   
    int x[] = new int[100];    // k <= 100
    System.out.println("All " + k + "-combinations of " + n + " numbers:"); 
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) 
       x[j] = j+1;
    while (true) {
       printArray(x, k);
       if (nextCombination(x, k, n) == false) 
          break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? The algorithm seems to work as intended when i ran it. (Edit: Of course I had to initialize x[] with some distinguishable values)

Comment: @samjaf 
How can I modify the first for loop in this java method into a recursive call?

Comment: So you want change `nextCombination(int[], int, int)` to be recursive and dismiss `for (int j = k-1; j >= 0; j--)` in it?

Comment: @samjaf That's what I've gathered from the problem description.

Comment: Hmm... nice assignment. I'm giving it some thought.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output of what the algorithm is supposed to do?

Comment: Presumably you can, since that's what you were asked to. Have you tried to? What part were you struggling with?

Comment: @sdasdadas if the input is 2 and 5 it'll output
1,2...
1,3...
1,4...
...
2,3...
2,4...
2,5...
...
5,1...
5,2...
etc...

it returns all combinations of k numbers from 1 to n

Comment: I stopped thinking since omaeinegras solution is nice, simple and straightforward ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you transform the `nextCombination` method into a recursive one.

```
public static boolean nextCombinationRecursive (int j, int x[], int k, int n) {
    if (j < 0 || j > k) return false;

    if (x[j] <= (n - k + j)) {
        x[j]++;  
        for (int i = 1; i < k - j;  i++)
            x[i+j] = x[j]+i;
        return true; 
    }

    return nextCombinationRecursive(j - 1, x, k, n);
}
```

And you call it from `enumerateCombinations` like this:

```
if (nextCombinationRecursive(k - 1, x, k, n) == false)
```